# pythonのリスト内の重複要素検索

Tags: python

python(2.7.10)で，list内の検索をする際

> In[1]: a = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5]
>   In[2]: a.index(3)
>   Out[2]: 2

と最初のインデックスが返ってきます．
理想は[2,3,4]と全ての該当インデックスが欲しいのですが，簡単な書き方で取得できる方法はありませんか．

今のところ可能な限り要素を検索しつつ取得した場所を取り除き続けるという力技をしていますがもう少し簡潔でメモリに優しい方法はないでしょうか
(元のリストはそのままにしておきたいのでdeepcopyをしていますがメモリを食ってしまうようで大きいリストで大量に実行すると止まってしまいます…)

```
from copy import deepcopy
b = deepcopy(a)
ans = []
while True:
  try:   
    ans.append(b.index(3))
    b.pop(b.index(3))
  except:
    break
```

Comment: 質問の例ですと、「ans」と「b」という二つのリストを作っていますが、両方必要ですか？リストbが必要だとして、3は一つも含まれない事になるかと思いますが、それでよいですか？それとも「重複」している（2回目以降に現われる）3だけ取り除きたいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

単純にforで

```
ans = []
for index, value in enumerate(a):
    if value == 3:
        ans.append(index)
```

---

内包表記で

```
ans = [ i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == 3]
```

Comment: なるほど！
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

巨大なリストを扱うのであれば、イテレータが望ましいと思います。

ビルトインの`list`からサブクラス`ext_list`を設け、`indices`メソッドをジェネレータとして実装してはどうでしょうか。

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

class ext_list(list):
    def indices(self, v):
        for i, elm in enumerate(self):
            if elm is v:
                yield i

from pprint import pprint

a = ext_list([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5])
pprint(list(a.indices(3)))
```

結果:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

もちろんメモリを気にするのであれば、この結果の後処理もイテレータで扱う必要があるのですが。

Comment: indicesだけで十分で、クラスにする必要は無いと思います

Comment: うーん・・・たしかにそうかもしれない

Answer (score -1):

numpyのnp.whereを使う方法はどうでしょうか。

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5]

In [3]: np.where(map(lambda x: x == 3, a))
Out[3]: (array([2, 3, 4]),)
```